# Вывод таблицы и ее цвета по условию

Tags: php

Я читаю значение в файле, вписываю его в переменную ***$read***, и по идее в зависимости от считанного ***$read*** с помощью **if(...){...}** я вывожу таблицу и, смотря что я считал в ***$read***, я вывожу **цвет** таблицы.

То есть, если вписано "Онлайн" то зеленый, а если "Оффлайн" то красный. Помогите это осуществить, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.red {border: 1px; background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}
.green {border: 1px; background-color: #00ff00; color: #000000;}
.gray {border: 1px; background-color: #999999; color: #000000;}
```

и

```
if ($read == 'Онлайн')
{
    echo '<table class="green">';
} else 
if ($read == 'Офлайн')
{ 
    echo '<table class="red">';
} else
if ($read == 'На регистрации')
{ 
    echo '<table class="grey">';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще такого рода вещи лучше делать уже через switch():

так что можно взять css из первого варианта

```
.red {border: 1px; background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}
.green {border: 1px; background-color: #00ff00; color: #000000;}
.gray {border: 1px; background-color: #999999; color: #000000;}
```

а вот в php сделать так:

```
switch ($read) {
    case 'Онлайн':
        echo '<table class="green">';
        break;
    case 'Оффлайн':
        echo '<table class="red">';
        break;
    case 'На регистрации':
        echo '<table class="grey">';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.red {border: 1px; background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}
.green {border: 1px; background-color: #00ff00; color: #000000;}
.gray {border: 1px; background-color: #999999; color: #000000;}
```

Код на PHP:

```
$tableColor = array('Онлайн' => 'green','Офлайн' => 'red','На регистрации' => 'gray');
echo '<table class="'.$tableColor[$read].'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

if ($read == "Онлайн")
{
print `<table class='green'>`;
}
else 
{
echo `<table class='red'>`
}
Как-то так.